# Proof General complaining script incomplete if running 2 scripts at the same time

Tags: coq, proof-general

It seems like PG doesn't allow running 2 scripts at the same time. The moment attempting to do this, Emacs will prompt and ask to retract the other file. Sometimes, scripts are nontrivial to rerun. Is there any way to actually run 2(or more) scripts in a single Emacs instance? I don't think the coqide gui shipped with coq has no such problem.

Comment: is this issue also present for Isabelle, or is this just a Coq problem? (like is it a ProofGeneral problem in general). I just don't understand how the workflow for ProofGeneral is supposed to look like if one can't even edit 2 files at the same time. Seems ridiculous to me.

Comment: @Pinocchio it's not a Coq problem for sure. Coq checks consistency between .vo whenever it loads something. I suppose it's a consequence of legacy software design, e.g. too many globals as pointed out below.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem possible with the current version of PG. Here is an excerpt from the [Proof General manual](https://proofgeneral.github.io/doc/userman/ProofGeneral_4/#Switching-between-proof-scripts):

> However, you cannot have more than one buffer where only a fraction of the proof script contains a locked region. Before you can employ script management in another proof script buffer, you must either fully assert or retract the current script buffer.

Comment: yeah i saw that as well. i am not sure i understand why such limitation exists, and the explanation in the doc is not clear enough. i think it's probably due to there is only one coqtop instance running in the background, and it doesn't seem possible to raise the number of processes. any chance you have some insight?

Comment: See my answer. The problem is that Proof General has an unfortunate dependence on global variables.

Comment: The fact that one cannot work with multiple files seems really strange to me. Then how does actually develop medium size projects with at least 2 files with PG and emacs?

Comment: @Pinocchio I sometimes use two (and never really needed more) instances of Emacs to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the current Proof General has too many global variables in use to allow multiple script instances to be executed simultaneously. Apparently there is some work in progress to fix this by encapsulating the global state, but I have no idea when it might be completed.

Comment: if this is the case then how is one suppose to work on multiple scripts at the same time with proof General? How does the workflow with ProofGeneral work? It seems some of the most basic things aren't allowed so I don't understand how people can use PG without getting extremely annoyed/confused (especially with multiple files going on at once).